# codeigniter parse and replace bbcode

Tags: codeigniter, bbcode

I use BBCode Helper.
helper code:

```
function parse_bbcode($str = ''){

$find = array(
  "'\[v\](.*?)\[/v\]'is"
);

$replace = array(
  '<video>\1</video>'
);

return preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);

}
```

controller:

```
$this->load->helper('bbcode');

$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3, 1));

foreach ($data['news'] as $key=>$val)
{
  parse_bbcode($data['news'][$key]['description']); 
}
```

for example i want to replace [v]vid[/v] to vid.
replacement does not work (nothing happens). what I did wrong?

Comment: Does not work how? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to say what i want. i updated first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong.

This works:

```
$video = "[v]testvid.swf[/v]";

$re = '/\[v](.+)\[\/v\]/i';

$replace = '<video>\1</video>';

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($re, $replace, $video));
```

Outputs:

```
<video>testvid.swf</video>
```

---

http://regexpal.com/ is a good resource for working out regex issues.

Comment: Impossible to tell without looking at the contents of `$data['news']`. Here's a working example with an array: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bMrZmi

Comment: $data['news] it's array of posts. every post contain id, title, description.